# iPhone 5 screen toggle on storyboard not working on all view controllers (the actual controllers and stuff inside)

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

For some reason, when I click the little button in storyboard, some of the view controllers fail to expand (I mean the view controller itself as well as the stuff inside it). What's really peculiar is that some of the view controllers that did expand then get stuck that way when I tap the button again (again, I mean the view controller itself and the stuff inside it). Now, when I hit the button, only a few move, while the others remain stuck. What did I do wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by 'little button in storyboard' and 'fail to expand'? And are you talking about in storyboard view or runtime? Want to post a screenshot?

Comment: He's referring to the button in the storyboard editor that toggles between the iPhone 3.5 inch form factor and the iPhone 4 inch form factor.  It's the leftmost button of the row of buttons at the bottom right, and only appears when editing a storyboard, not when editing a xib. The same toggle is available as the last item in the Editor menu, labelled either “Apply Retina 4-inch Form Factor” or “Apply Retina 3.5-inch Form Factor” (depending on the currently applied form factor).

Comment: Make sure all of your view controllers have a size of “Inferred” in their Simulated Metrics under the Attributes Inspector.  Also, tell us whether any of these view controllers are embedded (contained) in other view controllers.